# What's next in this letter sequence: A, H, I, M, O, T, . .

Tags: letter-sequence, letters

What would come next in this sequence, and what is the source?
**A, H, I, M, O, T, . . .**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next letter would be

> U

Because

> The sequence is of vertically symmetric letters, and U is the one after T.